# Pure JS add class not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a site I'm making and it has this code in the HTML:

```
<div id="close" onclick="close()"></div>
```

There's also some JS which has this:

```
function close() {
  document.getElementById("glass1").setAttribute("class", "hidden");
}
```

But when I click close it doesn't seem to work. You can see the site at http://galaxy-os.koding.com to see what I mean. Please help

Comment: `element.className` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.className) is IMO a bit better for using classes than `setAttribute('class', ...)`. Also if you don't car about old browsers: `element.classList` is pretty cool https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.classList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your element `id` is colliding with the function name `close`.

I would recommend changing the function name as it sounds way too generic anyway.